# How to get exception details and method returned value from method

Tags: java, methods, return

how to get method return value isFailed along with exception details if method is failed

```
    class sample
    {
        booelan isFailed=false;
        boolean m1()
        {
        try{
          logic of method
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         String cause=e.getMessage();
         isFailed=true;
        }
        return isFailed;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't catch the exception: if the caller detects than an exception was thrown, it has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the calling method needs to know about the `Exception`, just let it go through.

`m1` doesn't have to return a boolean, it either worked or threw an Exception, so the calling method will know whether it is a success or not.

In this example, the calling method (`m1Caller`) is in the same class for simplicity .

```
class sample {

    boolean isFailed = false;

    void m1() throws Exception {
        // logic of method
    }

    void m1Caller() {

        try {

            m1();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // do whatever you want with the Exception's message
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            isFailed = true;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response,
but i want to send method response failed or success.
if failed i need cause of failure and status as Failed

Comment: @Mahender : if you really need several information at once, create an Object wrapping a boolean variable and an Exception variable, and return that.